# How to find the request-URL from inside Greasemonkey's GM_xmlhttpRequest "onload" callback in case of 302 redirect?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, asynccallback, gm-xmlhttprequest

I have a [`GM_xmlhttpReqeust`](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest) function setup as follows (simplified version) in my Greasemonkey script.

```
  GM_xmlhttpRequest({
    synchronous: false,
    method: "HEAD",
    url: "http://www.example1.com",
    onload: function(response){console.debug(url);},
  });
```

- `GM_xmlhttpReqeust` is called in ***asynchronous*** mode in my code.
- Once accessed, `http://www.example1.com` does a ***302 redirect*** to `http://www.example2.com`
- I would like to access the value of the original `url` parameter (`http://www.example1.com`) inside `onload` callback function.
- As per `GM_xmlhttpReqeust` [documentation](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest), `http://www.example2.com` can be found in `response.finalUrl` inside `onload` callback.

Could someone please point me to the proper Greasemonkey/JavaScript way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `response` passed to `onload` is [an *object* with these key properties](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest#Response_Object):

- readyState
- responseHeaders
- responseText
- status
- statusText
- finalUrl

You want `finalUrl`, you get it like:

```
GM_xmlhttpRequest ( {
    synchronous:    false,
    method:         "HEAD",
    url:            "http://www.google.com",
    onload:         function (response) {
        console.debug (response.finalUrl);
    }
} );
```

---

---

## Update for revised/clarified question:

In order to get/know the originally requested URL, you must call `GM_xmlhttpRequest()` in a [*closure*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/111102/331508).  Like so:

```
var origURL = "http://www.google.com";

(function (targURL) {
    GM_xmlhttpRequest ( {
        synchronous:    false,
        method:         "HEAD",
        url:            targURL,
        onload:         function (response) {
            console.log ("orig URL: ", targURL);
            console.log ("final URL: ", response.finalUrl);
        }
    } );
} ) (origURL);
```

Comment: Hi @Brock Adams, Actually I don't want the `finalUrl`. I'll change `http://www.google.com` to `http://www.example1.com`. `http://www.example1.com` does a 302 redirect to `http://www.example2.com` which is found in `finalUrl`. I would like to get the original request URL which is `http://www.example1.com` as set in `url` parameter to `GM_xmlhttpReqeust`. I am going to change the question for more clarity. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 2):

I got a stupid solution below, I hope it will work.

```
GM_xmlhttpRequest ( {
    synchronous:    false,
    method:         "HEAD",
    url:            "http://www.google.com",
    onload:         function (response) {
        console.debug (this.url);
    }
} );
```

Comment: Hi @Zhou Lee, the doc is here http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest, but it's not obvious how to access the `url` from inside `onload` callback.

Comment: Close, but `url` would still not be defined inside `onload`.  *However*, since your solution passes an object, it can use the `this` scope to access `url`.  I took the liberty of fixing the answer for you, and it does work after my tweak. ... PS:  this is just another way to do a closure.

Comment: Huh.  Yeah, you're right. Already upvoted.  Although this is a bad habit to be in, as different functions/cases might override `this`.  For this specific question, it should be OK.

Comment: Thanks. I tested both yours and Brock's solutions and they both work. If I could accept two, I would have accepted your solution as correct as well. I have up-voted you and accepting @Brock's solution as correct for demonstrating the more accurate JavaScript way. Thanks again to you both.

Answer (score 0):

referring to

http://userscripts-mirror.org/topics/51161

Firstly you need:

```
var method = this;
  var oldargs = [].slice.call( arguments, 1 );
  return function () {
    var newargs = [].slice.call( arguments );
    return method.apply( thisObject, oldargs.concat( newargs ));
  };
}
```

Then you go, similar way...

[image]